# A map is homogenous iff $r\mathbb{B}(1) = \mathbb{B}(|r|)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

On [Planet Math](https://planetmath.org/seminorm) it is stated that th homogenity of a semi-norm is equivalent to the fact  that $r\mathbb{B}(1) = \mathbb{B}(|r|).$ I interpret this that for any real-valued map on a vector space for which homogenity is equivalent to this unit-ball property. This would give a nice geometric characterisation of homogenity.

However I can only show $p(r v) \leq |r| p(v),$ the other direction eludes me. Is this claim correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we know that $p(rv) \leq |r|p(v)$ whenever $v \in V$ and $r \in K$.  We then know that
\begin{align*}
p(v) = |r|^{-1} |r| p(r^{-1} \cdot r v) \leq |r|^{-1} p(rv)
\end{align*}
which gives $|r| p(v) \leq p(rv)$ and hence equality.

Comment: Ah yes, I somehow thought that the condition on the unit balls also needs to enter here. Thanks!